# Problem iterating map in visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to iterate inner map in visualforce

`Public Map<String,Map<String,String>> planMetadataMap {get;set;}`

This is my datatype

```html
    <apex:repeat value="{!planMetadataMap}" var="planMain">
        <apex:repeat value="{!planMain}" var="mapSubPlan">
            <td>${!qliWrapper.planMap[mapSubPlan['Pharma']]}</td>
            <td>${!qliWrapper.planMap[mapSubPlan['Non-Pharma']]}</td>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:repeat>
```

I am trying to iterate it like, it's not letting me save, saying
Expression of type Text cannot be subscripted.

The sample value  in my map would be ---

```
<Plan_General_Name,<<Pharma,Plan_Specific_Name>,<Non-Pharma,Plan_Specific_Name>>>,
```

I want to get Plan_Specific_Name to get it from the `qliWrapper.planMap[Plan_Specific_Name]`

What's the solution on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to iterate over `planMetadataMap` in the first repeat to get the inner `Map`, the var for the first `repeat` would be the `key` of the outer map. Then using that `key`, access the `inner map` and then again iterate using the `repeat` tag wherein the var for the inner `repeat` would be the `key` of the `inner map`. Now, to access the values in the map, you should use `planMetadataMap` variable with both the `keys`. So your visualforce code would be

```
<apex:repeat value="{!planMetadataMap}" var="planMain">
    <apex:repeat value="{!planMetadataMap[planMain]}" var="mapSubPlan"> 
        <td>${!planMetadataMap[planMain][mapSubPlan]}</td>
    </apex:repeat> 
</apex:repeat>
```

With your sample data, this is how it will be, you can remove the `keys` and the `line breaks` that is just added for better understanding

```
<apex:repeat value="{!planMetadataMap}" var="planMain">
    {!planMain} <!--this is key of outer map i.e. Plan_General_Name--><br/> 
    <apex:repeat value="{!planMetadataMap[planMain]}" var="mapSubPlan"> 
        <br/>{!mapSubPlan} <!--this is key of inner map i.e. Pharma  or Non-Pharma--><br/>
        ${!planMetadataMap[planMain][mapSubPlan]} <!--this is the final value i.e. Plan_Specific_Name-->
    </apex:repeat> 
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: The `$` in this case is to show it's a dollar amount, not part of the merge field.

Comment: Ahh I see, updated the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Worked. any idea if I can sort the inner map :D